# Bash guard / chainring guard for asymmetric cranks

Tags: shimano

Short version: Where can I purchase a bash guard / chainring guard for 110 BCD asymmetric 4-bolt used by SHIMANO GRX Gravel Crankset FC-RX600-10 46-30T?

Long version: I recently purchased SHIMANO GRX Gravel Crankset (2x10-speed FC-RX600-10 46-30T, 170mm) to be installed on my Tern Eclipse P20 folding bike. Since I will frequently folding my bike, teeth on the crankset might hit on someone causing injury or hit on the ground causing damage to the crankset while transportation in a folded state. I would like to purchase chainring guard to avoid this, but I searched on the Internet and couldn't find one suitable for my GRX crankset. I found [a discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MTB/comments/d59jrw/bash_guard_for_shimano_asymmetric_cranks/) but is not useful. Trying my luck here to see if there is any help I can receive.

Comment: If I read the question correctly it sounds like all of the injury/damage you are trying to avoid would happen when the bike is folded, while being transported. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, here is a [photo](https://www.ternbicycles.com/sites/default/files/images/bikes/folded/2015/09/eclipsep20-fold-00-blk-red.jpg) of the bike folded. Maybe I shall switch to the largest crank before fold to avoid the teeth hitting anything.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of edge trim products designed to slip over a metal edge to protect both the metal edge and people. Searching on "metal edge protector" generated some good results.

Here are a few of dozens of types
[image]
[The Rubber Company](https://therubbercompany.com/extrusions-profiles/composite-self-grip/pvc-self-grip-edge-trim)  (only an example, not a recommendation)
[Trim Lok](https://www.trimlok.com/) is another large maker of edge protection

They can be made of PVC, rubber and many other materials.

It will take a little experimenting to find the right mix of flexibility, size and strength. Once you find the edge trim that fits and will curve around the chainring you would cut the trim to the correct length so that it neatly grips the chainring.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it will be very inconvenient compared to chainring guard as I have to install them after riding and uninstall them before riding. A chainring guard is still the best option.

Comment: @VCD I have updated the answer to include a chainring / bash guard answer.

Comment: I have actually asked BBG Bashguard before asking here, and they replied that they did not make those chainring guard for **asymmetric** bolt pattern, and they cannot make custom guard.

Comment: @VCD Thank you. I have corrected my post